# How to write two dictionaries to CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, file-writing

I was wondering how I could iterate over two dictionaries: `yin` and `BL`.

I have the following code so far to iterate over `yin` only:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
  writer = csv.writer(output)
  for key, value in yin.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

`yin` has values in a dictionary:

```
{'a': 2248433.0, 'b': 280955.0, 'c': 0.0}
```

`BL` has values in a dictionary:

```
{'a': 27.2, 'b': 57.6, 'c': 0.0}
```

I want to save it to an excel file so it looks like:

```
a  2248433.0    27.2     
b  280955.0     57.6   
c  0.0           0.0
```

Should I do the following?

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
  writer = csv.writer(output)
  for key, value, valye in yin.iteritems(), BL.iteritems:
    writer.writerow([key, value, value])
```

I also want the dictionaries to be listed in the same corresponding order in the CSV file. As shown in the table, I want `row1: 2248433.0` to correspond to `27.2`.

This was the code used to generate dictionaries:

```
yin = {}
BL = {}
  for asdf in glob.glob(ay):
    poregn = numpy.genfromtxt(asdf)
    btwnROIs = poregn[2:size+2, 0:size] 
    BLu = poregn[(size*5)+2:(size*5)+size+2, 0:size]
    for upmatSC in (list(combinations(range(size_FC),2))):
      yin[FC_path1 + '_' + FC_path2 + '_' + str(upmatSC)] = btwnROIs[tuple(upmatSC)]
      BL[FC_path1 + '_' + FC_path2 + '_' + str(upmatSC)] = BLu[tuple(upmatSC)]
```

To explain the code: basically I'm taking two separate matrices and extracting the upper half of each of the matrix and storing these values in two separate dictionaries.

Comment: Why ask us? Try it out. Nothing will explode if you do. If you observe behaviour that you can not fix yourself, ask.

Comment: I already tried... and it didn't work. that's why I'm asking. thanks.. @PatrickArtner

Comment: ^ what Patrick said ... but one thing to keep in mind is that dictionaries are unordered internally, so you are going to need to think of how you are mapping keys in yin to keys in BL.

Comment: @J.Taylor How can I do that? That was the second part of my question.

Comment: @J.Taylor dictionaries, _prior to Python 3.6_, are unordered.

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh - I didn't realize that had changed since 3.6!

Comment: @roganjosh Would you happen to know if there's some way I could order it?

Comment: @J.Taylor in 3.6 it is an implementation detail. In 3.7 it is guaranteed

Comment: Are you generating the dict yourself @hsayya? If so, and order is important then, create lists of tuples or use something like collections.OrderedDict instead of storing the values in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating them myself.  I could try to look into orderedDict @J.Taylor

Comment: If you are generating these yourself then the dictionary was potentially a bad choice. Why do you end up with 2 dicts where you rely on order to marry them together? This problem would probably be better addressed upstream where you create the data structures.

Comment: @roganjosh I added the code I used to generate the dictionaries, if you could please take a look at it.

Comment: That code can't generate tthe example dictionaries you've given because they would share keys. In your example, the keys are different.

Comment: @roganjosh my bad, I realized that was a mistake.  You're right the keys would be the same.

Comment: @roganjosh In that case, since the keys are the same, how could I accomplish what I'm trying to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two dictionaries `yin` and `bl`, this would be how you would combine the dictionaries in the manner you described and write them to a CSV file:

```
import csv 

yin = {'a': 2248433.0, 'b': 280955.0, 'c': 0.0}
bl = {'a': 27.2, 'b': 57.6, 'c': 0.0}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    cw = csv.writer(output)

    for k in yin.keys():
      cw.writerow([k, yin[k], bl[k]])
```